# Fetch latest data based on timestamp using ElasticSearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic search and  need a help with an ES query. I have an elastic search index with record as follows(sorted based on timestamp)

| TimeStamp | StoreID | BookStoreName | RackID | RackName | BookID | BookName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-31T09:33:41Z | 122r3 | ABC | 122r34 | XYZ | 122e33r | abc |
| 2023-07-31T09:32:41Z | 122r3 | ABCD | 122r35 | XYZA | 1298e33r | hb78 |
| 2023-07-31T09:31:41Z | 122r3 | ABCE | 122r34 | XYZ1 | 9086795s | 8hb7 |
| 2023-07-31T09:30:41Z | 122r3 | ABCF | 122r34 | XYZ2 | 132lkg h | kho97 |

In this doc for a single StoreID there can have multiple RackID and with in this combination there will be lot of data available(BookID & BookName). Looking for an ES query to find the latest record for a StoreID &  RackID combination. Eg here for StoreID(122r3) & RackID(122r34) there are 3 records, need to get the latest record which is below one.

| 2023-07-31T09:33:41Z | 122r3 | ABC | 122r34 | XYZ | 122e33r | abc |

I am using Elastic search 7 & Tried Bool Must query which returns all the record. Need only the latest record based on timestamp.

Also is it possible to get the result for multiple combination also so that with a single query latest records can be fetched for all StoreID  & RackID combination.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to achieve the latest record.

1. `size` + `sort` by timestamp
2. `top_hits` aggregation

### Here is an example:

###### create the index

```
POST _bulk
{"index": {"_index": "test_sort_by_timestamp"}}
{"TimeStamp": "2023-07-31T09:33:41Z", "StoreID": "122r3", "BookStoreName": "ABC", "RackID": "122r34", "RackName": "XYZ", "BookID": "122e33r", "BookName":     "abc"}
{"index": {"_index": "test_sort_by_timestamp"}}
{"TimeStamp": "2023-07-31T09:32:41Z", "StoreID": "122r3", "BookStoreName": "ABCD", "RackID": "122r35", "RackName": "XYZA", "BookID": "1298e33r", "BookName":    "hb78"}
{"index": {"_index": "test_sort_by_timestamp"}}
{"TimeStamp": "2023-07-31T09:31:41Z", "StoreID": "122r3", "BookStoreName": "ABCE", "RackID": "122r34", "RackName": "XYZ1", "BookID": "9086795s", "BookName":    "8hb7"}
{"index": {"_index": "test_sort_by_timestamp"}}
{"TimeStamp": "2023-07-31T09:30:41Z", "StoreID": "122r3", "BookStoreName": "ABCF", "RackID": "122r34", "RackName": "XYZ2", "BookID": "132lkgh", "BookName":     "kho97"}
```

###### `size` + `sort` by timestamp

```
GET test_sort_by_timestamp/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "StoreID.keyword": "122r3"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "RackID.keyword": "122r34"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "latest_record": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 1,
        "sort": [
          {
            "TimeStamp": {
              "order": "desc"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

###### `top_hits` aggregation

```
GET test_sort_by_timestamp/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "StoreID.keyword": "122r3"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "RackID.keyword": "122r34"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "TimeStamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
GET test_sort_by_timestamp/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "RackID.keyword": ["122r34", "122r35"]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "StoreID.keyword": "122r3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "TimeStamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

2. EDIT

---

```
GET test_sort_by_timestamp/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "store_rack_combinations": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['StoreID.keyword'].value + '|' + doc['RackID.keyword'].value"
        },
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_record": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "TimeStamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Is it possible to get the latest records for multiple combinations like 
StoreID(122r3) & RackID(122r34) and also for StoreID(122r3) & RackID(122r35). Result as below
| 2023-07-31T09:32:41Z | 122r3| ABCD | 122r35 | XYZA | 1298e33r | hb78 |
| 2023-07-31T09:33:41Z | 122r3 | ABC | 122r34 | XYZ | 122e33r | abc |

Idea is to get the latest records for all StoreID & RackID combination.

Comment: this gives only the single record. I am trying to get latest record from each unique combination of StoreID & RackID. After lot of search found that this can can be achieved using collapse & inner_hits but the down side of this approach is that it gives duplicate data in the inner_hits when inner_hit size is 1. Any idea? when I tried inner_hits size=0 got the below error
`numHits must be > 0; please use TotalHitCountCollector if you just need the total hit count"`

Comment: now you cleared the request :) answer updated.